# Getting the same data for all the records for editing and updating a record in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am having two different database tables questions and choices where i am inserting questions in one table and multiple choices in another table where questions table id is foreign key in choices table.

Questions:

```
Questions_number  Text
1                 What is HTML?
2                 What is PHP?
```

Choices:

```
id    question_number  is_correct   text
1          1             1           markup
2          1             0           Hyext
3          1             0           Hyper text markup language
4          2             0           hsdfd
5          2             0           frfwer
6          2             1           Hypertext Preprocessor
```

If i am trying to edit question number 1 then i need to fetch all the details of questions,Choices and correct option as well.But when i am trying to edit the record for choices as well i am getting the same data which i am getting for question.

HTML:

```
<?php session_start();
include 'includes/db.php';  
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions q WHERE q.question_number = $id ";
$oppointArr =array();
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {          
        $oppointArr = $row;
        echo "Text: " . $row["text"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}   
?>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="updatequestions.php" method="post" role="form">
<?php if(isset($msg)) {?>
                                <div class="<?php echo $msgclass; ?>"  id="mydiv" style="padding:5px;"><?php echo $msg; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
                            <input  type='hidden' value='<?=$id;?>' name='question_number'>
                              <h2>Edit A Question</h1>

                                <div class="form-group"> 
                                    <label for="questionno" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Question Number</label> 
                                    <div class="col-sm-5"> 
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $oppointArr['question_number'];?>" 
                                        name="question_number" id="question_number" readonly> 
                                    </div> 
                                </div>  
                                <div class="form-group"> 
                                    <label for="question" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Question</label> 
                                    <div class="col-sm-5"> 
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $oppointArr['text'];?>" name="question_text" id="question_text"> 
                                    </div> 
                                </div> 

                                <input  type='hidden' value='<?=$id;?>' name='id'>
                                  <h2>Edit A Choice</h1>

                                <div class="form-group"> 
                                    <label for="choice #1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Choice #1</label> 
                                    <div class="col-sm-5"> 
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $oppointArr['choice1'];?>" name="choice1" id="choice1"> 
                                    </div> 
                                </div> 

                               <div class="form-group"> 
                                    <label for="choice #2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Choice #2</label> 
                                    <div class="col-sm-5"> 
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $oppointArr['choice2'];?>" name="choice2" id="choice2"> 
                                    </div> 
                                </div>  
                               <div class="form-group"> 
                                    <label for="choice #3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Choice #3</label> 
                                    <div class="col-sm-5"> 
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $oppointArr['choice3'];?>" name="choice3" id="choice3"> 
                                    </div> 
                                </div>                                                                                                                              
                                  <div class="form-group"> 
                                    <label for="Correct Choice Number:" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Correct Choice Number:</label> 
                                    <div class="col-sm-5"> 
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $oppointArr['is_correct'];?>" name="is_correct" id="is_correct"> 
                                    </div> 
                                </div>  
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-2"> 
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit_user" id="subject">Submit</button> 
                                    <button type="cancel" class="btn btn-raised"><a href="http://localhost/quizzeradmin/admin/searchquestions.php">Cancel</a></button>
                                </div> 
                            </form>
```

Updatequestions:

```
<?php
include 'includes/db.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit_user']))
{
    $questiontext = $_POST['question_text'];
    $id=$_POST['question_number'];
    $correct_choice = $_POST['correct_choice'];
    $choices = array();
    $choices[1] = $_POST['choice1'];
    $choices[2] = $_POST['choice2'];
    $choices[3] = $_POST['choice3'];
    $choices[4] = $_POST['choice4'];
    $choices[5] = $_POST['choice5'];
    $query = "UPDATE questions SET text='$questiontext' WHERE question_number = $id";               
    $insert_row = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    if($insert_row) {
        foreach($choices as $choice => $value){
            if($value != ''){
                if($correct_choice == $choice){
                    $is_correct = 1;
                } else {
                    $is_correct = 0;
                }
                $query = "UPDATE choices SET  is_correct='$is_correct', text='$value' WHERE question_number=$id";
                $insert_row = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);               
                if($insert_row){
                    continue;
                } else {
                    die('Error : ('.$mysqli->errno . ') '. $mysqli->error);
                }
            }
        }
        $msg = 'Question has been added';
    }
}
?>
```

If i try to update the record all the  fields are updating with the same data.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="updatequestions.php" method="post" role="form">
                            <?php if(isset($msg)) {?>
                                <div class="<?php echo $msgclass; ?>"  id="mydiv" style="padding:5px;"><?php echo $msg; ?></div>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <input  type='hidden' value='<?=$id;?>' name='question_number'>
                              <h2>Edit A Question</h1>

                                <div class="form-group"> 
                                    <label for="questionno" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Question Number</label> 
                                    <div class="col-sm-5"> 
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $oppointArr['question_number'];?>" 
                                        name="question_number" id="question_number" readonly> 
                                    </div> 
                                </div>  
                                <div class="form-group"> 
                                    <label for="question" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Question</label> 
                                    <div class="col-sm-5"> 
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $oppointArr['text'];?>" name="question_text" id="question_text"> 
                                    </div> 
                                </div> 

                                <input  type='hidden' value='<?=$id;?>' name='id'>
                                  <h2>Edit A Choice</h1>
                                  <?php

                                        $choicesql = "SELECT * FROM `choices`  WHERE question_number = $id ";
                                        $ChoicetArr =array();
                                        $choiceresult = mysqli_query($mysqli,$choicesql);
                                        $inc=1;
                                        $correctAns  ="";

                                        if (mysqli_num_rows($choiceresult) > 0) 
                                        {
                                          while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($choiceresult)) 
                                          {   
                                                $ChoicetArr[] = $rows;


                                           ?>

                                            <div class="form-group"> 
                                                <label for="choice #<?php echo $inc;?>" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Choice #<?php echo $inc;?></label> 
                                                <div class="col-sm-5"> 
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="choice_id<?php echo $inc;?>" value="<?php echo $rows['id'];?>">
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $rows['text'];?>" name="choice<?php echo $inc;?>" id="choice<?php echo $inc;?>"> 
                                                </div> 
                                            </div> 
                                            <?php 

                                            //print_r($rows);

                                            if($rows['is_correct']=="1"){ 

                                                $correctAns = '<input type="hidden" name="choice_id'.$inc.'" value="'.$rows['id'].'"><div class="form-group"> 
                                                    <label for="Correct Choice Number:" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Correct Choice Number:</label> 
                                                    <div class="col-sm-5"> 
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="'.$inc.'" name="is_correct" id="is_correct"> 
                                                    </div> 
                                                </div>';    
                                             }  
                                             $inc++;
                                          }
                                        }

                                        echo $correctAns;
                                 ?>

                                <div class="col-sm-offset-2"> 
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit_user" id="subject">Submit</button> 
                                    <button type="cancel" class="btn btn-raised"><a href="searchquestions.php">Cancel</a></button>
                                </div> 
                            </form>
```

updatequestions.php

```
<?php
include 'includes/db.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit_user']))
{
    $questiontext = $_POST['question_text'];
    $id=$_POST['question_number'];
    $correct_choice = $_POST['is_correct'];
    $choices = array();
    $choices[] = array("question"=>$_POST['choice1'], "answer"=>$_POST['choice_id1']);
    $choices[] = array("question"=>$_POST['choice2'], "answer"=>$_POST['choice_id2']);
    $choices[] = array("question"=>$_POST['choice3'], "answer"=>$_POST['choice_id3']);
    $choices[] = array("question"=>$_POST['choice4'], "answer"=>$_POST['choice_id4']);
    $choices[] = array("question"=>$_POST['choice5'], "answer"=>$_POST['choice_id5']);

    $query = "UPDATE questions SET text='$questiontext' WHERE question_number = $id";               
    $insert_row = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

    if($insert_row)
    {
        $inc= 0;

        foreach($choices as $choice => $value){
            if(count($value)>0){
                $answerInc = $choice+1;                 

                if($correct_choice == $answerInc){
                    $is_correct = 1;
                } else {
                    $is_correct = 0;
                }
                $text= $value['question'];
                $answer = $value['answer'];
                //echo "<br>".$text;
                //print_r($value);
                echo $answerInc;
                echo "<br>";

                echo $query = "UPDATE choices SET  is_correct='$is_correct', text='$text' WHERE id=$answer";
                $insert_row = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);               
                if($insert_row){
                    continue;
                } else {
                    die('Error : ('.$mysqli->errno . ') '. $mysqli->error);
                }
            }
            $inc++;
        }

        $msg = 'Question has been Updated Successfully';
        header("location:searchquestions.php");
        exit;
    }
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING: Do not create SQL statements by concatenating the data with SQL. Use prepared statements.**

As for your problem, you use the foreign key of the question to update choices. The key is not the primary key of choices and is not unique. Try using the unique primary key for your SQL.

Instead of this:

```
$query = "UPDATE choices SET  is_correct='$is_correct', text='$value' WHERE question_number=$id";
```

try this:

```
$query = "UPDATE choices SET  is_correct='$is_correct', text='$value' WHERE id=$choice ";
```

But of course you should really try to do it all over again using prepared statements instead!